# Using Time Travel Debugging with WinDbgX, how to start it even elevated?

Tags: windows-10, windbg

With WinDbg Preview (aka WinDbgX) -- i.e. the store app -- we have the option of using [Time Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) (TTD). I have used the corresponding feature in GDB on Linux before and only tried [the walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-walkthrough) once on an older Windows 10 point release.

Now I was trying to do it on Windows 10 20H2 (latest patches applied), and of course it requires elevation. However, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to start it elevated for the purpose of using TTD.

When I try I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Fatal error
---------------------------
WindowsDebugger.WindowsDebuggerException: Could not load dbghelp.dll from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2103.1004.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64 : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied

   at DbgX.DbgEngModule.LoadLibraryFromDirectory(String directory, String library)

   at DbgX.DbgEngModule.LoadDbgEngModule()

   at DbgX.EngineThread.ThreadProc()
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

... which "sort of" makes sense because `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` has restrictive ACLs set. However, I am member of the local administrators group, so I would have expected that to work.

How can *fix* this issue, being able to use TTD on Windows 10 20H2?

---

For anyone else encountering this issue, there is a workaround which - however - undermines the whole idea of app containers (but it works). If you use a tool such as `psexec` to start a command prompt as `nt authority\system`, you can copy the WinDbgX subdirectory from underneath `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` to another location, adjust its ACLs and run it from the new location (elevation works just like for any desktop app then, launching `DbgX.Shell.exe`).

Comment: I did something a bit different (I'm also running on a limited account). Get the url of windbg preview package [on the MS store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86) then go to [this website](https://store.rg-adguard.net/) (which allows to download a MS store package). Input the URL of the package (choose `URL (link)` in the dropdown) . Download the given `*.appx` file (it's a .zip, ~80MB). Extract the zip anywhere you see fit, right click on `DbgX.Shell.exe`, run as admin. Works every time for me.

Comment: Oh yeah, that should also work ... easier than using the `psexec` route!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this used to work haven't tried ttd lately
hit windows key + s
type windbg preview
right click runas administrator

[image]

edit

you can also try using runas /user:{machine}\Administrator  windbgx as below

[image]

you can read some gory details about the reparsepoints and addition of these ExecutionAlias path in %userpath% [here](https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2019/09/overview-of-windows-execution-aliases.html)

a sample code to dump the reparse points using DeviceIoControl()
you can also use **fsutil reparsepoints query filename** to get this data

main()

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void hexdump(unsigned char *buff, int size);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        if (GetFileAttributesA(argv[1]) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT)
        {
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL);
            if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                printf("opened the reparse point %p\n", hFile);
                unsigned char reparsebuff[0x1000] = {0};
                DWORD bytesreturned = 0;
                BOOL dcret = DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0,
                                             reparsebuff, 0x1000, &bytesreturned, NULL);
                if (dcret)
                {
                    printf("returned %x bytes\n", bytesreturned);
                    hexdump(reparsebuff, bytesreturned);
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    printf("usage %s <path to a reparse file like windbgx.exe>", argv[0]);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

hexdump()

```
void hexdump(unsigned char *buff, int size)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (j < size)
    {
        for (int i = j; i < j + 16; i++)
        {
            printf("%02x ", buff[i]);
        }
        printf("\t");
        for (int i = j; i < j + 16; i++)
        {
            if (buff[i] < 32 || buff[i] > 126)
            {
                printf(". ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c ", buff[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        j = j + 16;
    }
}
```

compiled linked and executed with vs2017 community

```
:\>cl /Zi /analyze /W4 /EHsc /Od /nologo reparsedumper.cpp /link /release
reparsedumper.cpp

:\>reparsedumper.exe
usage reparsedumper.exe <path to a reparse file like windbgx.exe>
:\>reparsedumper.exe "c:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\WinDbgX.exe"
opened the reparse point 00000000000000A8
returned 172 bytes
1b 00 00 80 6a 01 00 00 03 00 00 00 4d 00 69 00         . . . . j . . . . . . . M . i .
63 00 72 00 6f 00 73 00 6f 00 66 00 74 00 2e 00         c . r . o . s . o . f . t . . .
57 00 69 00 6e 00 44 00 62 00 67 00 5f 00 38 00         W . i . n . D . b . g . _ . 8 .
77 00 65 00 6b 00 79 00 62 00 33 00 64 00 38 00         w . e . k . y . b . 3 . d . 8 .
62 00 62 00 77 00 65 00 00 00 4d 00 69 00 63 00         b . b . w . e . . . M . i . c .
72 00 6f 00 73 00 6f 00 66 00 74 00 2e 00 57 00         r . o . s . o . f . t . . . W . 
69 00 6e 00 44 00 62 00 67 00 5f 00 38 00 77 00         i . n . D . b . g . _ . 8 . w .
65 00 6b 00 79 00 62 00 33 00 64 00 38 00 62 00         e . k . y . b . 3 . d . 8 . b .
62 00 77 00 65 00 21 00 4d 00 69 00 63 00 72 00         b . w . e . ! . M . i . c . r . 
6f 00 73 00 6f 00 66 00 74 00 2e 00 57 00 69 00         o . s . o . f . t . . . W . i .
6e 00 44 00 62 00 67 00 00 00 43 00 3a 00 5c 00         n . D . b . g . . . C . : . \ .
50 00 72 00 6f 00 67 00 72 00 61 00 6d 00 20 00         P . r . o . g . r . a . m .   .
46 00 69 00 6c 00 65 00 73 00 5c 00 57 00 69 00         F . i . l . e . s . \ . W . i .
6e 00 64 00 6f 00 77 00 73 00 41 00 70 00 70 00         n . d . o . w . s . A . p . p .
73 00 5c 00 4d 00 69 00 63 00 72 00 6f 00 73 00         s . \ . M . i . c . r . o . s .
6f 00 66 00 74 00 2e 00 57 00 69 00 6e 00 44 00         o . f . t . . . W . i . n . D .
62 00 67 00 5f 00 31 00 2e 00 32 00 30 00 30 00         b . g . _ . 1 . . . 2 . 0 . 0 .
37 00 2e 00 36 00 30 00 30 00 31 00 2e 00 30 00         7 . . . 6 . 0 . 0 . 1 . . . 0 .
5f 00 6e 00 65 00 75 00 74 00 72 00 61 00 6c 00         _ . n . e . u . t . r . a . l .
5f 00 5f 00 38 00 77 00 65 00 6b 00 79 00 62 00         _ . _ . 8 . w . e . k . y . b .
33 00 64 00 38 00 62 00 62 00 77 00 65 00 5c 00         3 . d . 8 . b . b . w . e . \ .
44 00 62 00 67 00 58 00 2e 00 53 00 68 00 65 00         D . b . g . X . . . S . h . e .
6c 00 6c 00 2e 00 65 00 78 00 65 00 00 00 30 00         l . l . . . e . x . e . . . 0 .
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00         . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

:\>
```

Comment: Well, that's what I am trying and when I receive said error.

Comment: edited in another possibility this is not 20h2 but 18363

Comment: Just tried, the clue was actually to execute windbgx.exe ... with that it works ... I had previously used the shortcut that was created by the store app.

Comment: Windbgx is a 0 byte reparse point file an executionalias read the contents of the  link i edited in

Comment: I also just realized it's a reparse point, even though none of my tools (not even my custom tools) are able to place a type on it. Thanks for the link.

Comment: added code to dump the reparse point 0 byte files

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the installation folder to some place else.
Although even to do so, might have to change the rights of the WinDbgX folder to even copy. Can use the "take ownership" way, etc.

Comment: Hi, I'm a huge fan of some of your work (in case it's really you). "Just" copying is not so easy. For me it involved using `psexec` to get system rights and then locate and copy it. It's arguably easier to attempt to fetch the installation package and unpack that into a location of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, my IDA plugins?
Yea unfortunately it installs with app container rights.
Get "take ownership registry download" 
Then right click on that "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" and take ownership.
But then I know that defeats the purpose of the restrictions MS put on it.
I do it in Windows 10 VM.